# Percolator-only elasticsearch cluster - is it worth having dedicated master nodes?

Tags: elasticsearch

I maintain an elasticsearch cluster on AWS (4x c4.xlarge.elasticsearch).
Its sole workload is percolator queries.

Dedicated master nodes are known to increase stability for larger clusters.

Does this apply to a cluster that only percolates or would it be overkill?

Comment: It depends on many factors, especially the amount of data your percolations run on. But I think that having three out of four nodes being data+master (and one data only) might be perfectly ok in your case.

Answer (score 0):

It better to have a dedicated master, but it comes with cost.
If we can afford some cost better to have 1 master and few data nodes for Percolator.

Alternative 2 Node with both roles(Master & Data) should be feasible solution